# Point in polygon check against lat and lng value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want to see if the latitude and longitude coordinates provided by the form are inside the polygon or not and then alert the user for both instances.

So far here is the code that I have. I have done some research and it has been said that you can use ray casting or you can use containsLocation() provided by the Google Maps API to do so. However I can not figure out how to use implement it.

Here is a demo http://codepen.io/simonfricker/pen/qbxOxy

**HTML**

```
<input id="location" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
<div id="map"></div>
```

**JS**

```
    var option = {
      types: ['(cities)'],
     // country: 'GB'
    };
    var latco, lngco;

 $("#location").geocomplete(option).bind("geocode:result", function(event, result) {
      latco = result.geometry.location.lat()
      lngco = result.geometry.location.lng()

      console.log(result.geometry.location.lng());
      console.log(result.geometry.location.lat());
    });

var map;
var src = 'http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Region/polygon-simple.kml';

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });
  loadKmlLayer(src, map);
}


function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(event) {
    var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
    var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
    testimonial.innerHTML = content;
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine the lat lngs of markers within a polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784807/determine-the-lat-lngs-of-markers-within-a-polygon)

Comment: You can't access the polygon data in a KML file displayed using KmlLayer, you need to create the polygon as a native Google Maps Javascript API v3 Polygon.  You can do that using a third party KML parser like [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [google.maps.KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml) does not expose any properties or methods for getting shapes on the map you could consider the following solution:

- convert KML file into GeoJSON format, for example using [this online
  converter](http://mapbox.github.io/togeojson/) ([converted file](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/741d25378f5ab8a19b0b))
- utilize GeoJSON file to display data layer on the map and then using [Google Maps Data API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) you could determine whether point is located inside a polygon or not as demonstrated below

```js
/**
 * Initializes the map and calls the function that creates polylines.
 */
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.93, 138.64),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    initGeocompleteControl(map,function (result) {
        map.data.forEach(function(f) {

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            calcBounds(f.getGeometry(),bounds);

            if (bounds.contains(result.geometry.location)) {
                $("#result").html('Location is found');
            } else {
                $("#result").html('Location is not found');
            }

        });
    });

    map.data.loadGeoJson('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vgrem/741d25378f5ab8a19b0b/raw/aef3ce18474db7a3482349f2a52cbd9d71caebc3/polygon-simple.json');
    
}

function initGeocompleteControl(map,complete) {
    var option = {
        types: ['(cities)']
        // country: 'GB'
    };
    $("#location").geocomplete(option).bind("geocode:result", function (event, result) {
        complete(result);
    });
}


function calcBounds(geometry,bounds) {
    if (geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
        bounds.extend(geometry);
    }
    else if (geometry instanceof google.maps.Data.Point) {
        bounds.extend(geometry.get());
    }
    else {
        geometry.getArray().forEach(function (g) {
           calcBounds(g,bounds);
        });
    }
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#map_div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geocomplete/1.6.5/jquery.geocomplete.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="location_container"class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <input id="location" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="map_div"></div>
```

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/dGdJmP)

Comment: Thanks, if there are two polygons can you detect which one the point is in?

Comment: Perhaps via the 'properties' tag in the json file?

Comment: Indeed, that's doable via the properties, for example: `properties: { key: "poly_cityname" }`

Comment: Here we go: [codepen](http://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/dGdJmP)  1)New property has been introduced in GeoJSON 2) Modified example to demonstrate how to read feature property

Comment: With more than one polygon it only seems to work in one. Please take a look at this pen http://codepen.io/simonfricker/pen/jWzOab

Comment: @vadim-gremyachev   It's not working with multiple polygons.
I create kml JSON file https://gist.github.com/rigalpatel001/cdc812514bff34e9d96ef3c147c7208d 

Would you please suggest a possible way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the polygon data in a KML file displayed using KmlLayer, you need to create the polygon as a native Google Maps Javascript API v3 Polygon. You can do that using a third party KML parser like [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/).

[example using geoxml3 with your KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geocodePointInPolygon_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/Adelaide_polygon-simple.kml)